# How to get the names of all files in a folder with path and with last modification date written into a CSV file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to get the filenames and date modified of all the files from a folder.

I had tried using the below command to get same. But it only gives me the list of files present in the folder and the date modified is missing.

Can someone help me out to modify the same and get the filenames and the date modified of the file as well.

```
dir /b /s > fileslist.csv
```

Comment: Try using a `for` loop. Using tokens and delims can get your work done quick. Also `/b` is for `bare`, which means to remove any information except the filenames

Answer (score 5):

From command line, to retrieve the required information

```dos
for /r %a in (*) do @echo %~ta %~fa
```

For each folder from the current one and below (recursive, `/r`), for each file (that will be referenced by `%a` replaceable parameter), echo the timestamp of the file (`%~ta`) and the full name of the file (`%~fa`)

To use it inside a batch file, percent signs in `for` replaceable parameters need to be doubled

```dos
for /r %%a in (*) do @echo %%~ta %%~fa
```

To send the output to a file, just redirect the full output of the command

```dos
>"file.csv" ( for /r %%a in (*) do @echo %%~ta,"%%~fa" )
```

***note***: read the output of `for /?` to get the reference of all the available options

Comment: -It really works..But i dont need the path..ONly file names required with date column

Comment: @Raul, then instead of `%~fa` (full path) use `%~nxa` (name and extension)

Comment: -Thanks a lot..Just a last thing..It also gives me the name of bat file and the excel file created..can that be eliminated??

Comment: -especially there are only zip files into the folder.

Comment: @Raul, change the mask inclusion from `*` to `*.zip`

Comment: -Is there any way out where i can hard code the dates and take the files between a specific period of time??

Comment: @Raul, Not without additional code, but, of course, it can be done. `forfiles`, `robocopy` or `wmic` can generate list of files with dates in specified ranges in locale or locale independent format. Try with them and if you found problems, please, start a new question showing what you tried and where you found problems so we can help you. Comments are too limited to handle more than basic changes.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your opening post and subsequent comments I'd use the `Where` command:

```dos
(For /F "Tokens=2-3*" %A In ('Where/T .:*.zip') Do @Echo(%A,"%~nxC")>output.csv
```

You could also quote `%A`, *(if you prefer that particular format)*.